# ¿Por qué no funciona mi metodo de subida de imagen? MVC .net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un problema, estoy intentando subir una imagen a mi carpeta local mediante el model MVC pero no lo funciona segun los ejemplos que he viso.
Tengo un modelo tal que :

```
 public partial class Usuario
    {
       public string Nombre { get; set; }
       (...)
       public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }    
    }
```

Y mi en mi vista de creacion generada por Visual Studio:

```
<div clas@using (Html.BeginForm())  s="form-horizontal">

    <hr />
    <div class="login-wrap">
        <div class="login-html">
            <input id="tab-2"  type="radio" name="tab" class="sign-up"><label for="tab-2" class="tab">Regístrate</label>
            <div class="login-form">

                <div class="sign-up-htm">
                    <br />
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nombre, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nombre, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nombre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

(...)
```

Todo funciona correctamente hasta que para seleccionar una imagen...
He probado:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.File.FileName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "file" } })
```

Y

```
<type="file" name="File"/>
```

Pero al llegar al controlador para manejar los datos:

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "Nombre,Apellidos,Mail,Pass,Nick,Generofav,Localidad,Pais,Direccion,Tipo,Telefono,Imagen,Codigo_validacion,Validado,File")] Usuario usuario)
        {
            **string filename = usuario.file.(...);**
```

Salta una excepción de objeto nulo:

```
 Detalles de la excepción: System.NullReferenceException: Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.
```

He seguido varios ejemplos pero no consigo que funcione. Muchas gracias, valoro su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Para que puedas enviar un archivo mediante un HTTP Post, sin ajax, debes **agregar el atributo enctype="multipart/form-data" a tu formulario**.
Otro detalle que veo es que el atributo name de tu input file se llama "File.FileName" (puedes validarlo inspeccionando el elemento en tu navegador). Para que tu propiedad File de tu clase Usuario se llene automaticamente, **debes renombrar el name en tu codigo de la vista .cshtml.**

Prueba este código.

**Código del controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
    public ActionResult ImagePrueba() {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ImagePrueba(Usuario usuario) {
        Debug.WriteLine(usuario.Nombre);
        return null;
    }
}

public partial class Usuario {
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

**Código del view:**

```
@model MvcApp.Controllers.Usuario

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>ImagePrueba</title>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ImagePrueba", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nombre, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nombre, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nombre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.File.FileName, null, "File", new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "file"} })
        <button>Enviar</button>
    }
</body>
</html>
```